# PHP - Concatenate values of 2 arrays into 1 new array

Tags: php

I have 2 separate multidimensional arrays that have the same structure. Example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => 1234 Main St
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => 5678 Elm St
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => 9879 New St
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => 9876 Shady Lane
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => Orlando
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => Tampa
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => Miami
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => West Palm Beach
        )

)
```

I just need to get them into 1 new array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => 1234 Main St Orlando
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => 5678 Elm St Tampa
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => 9879 New St Miami
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uploadData] => 9876 Shady Lane West Palm Beach
        )

)
```

I've been trying to use `array_merge` but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: You're going to have to build a custom function to do this.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: No, I was not 100% sure what built in functions I should even be using. Trying to figure that out now.

Comment: what if the arrays have different length ?

Comment: They will be the exact same length. I am sure of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, recursive, key-independent solution:

```php
function array_concat_recursive($array1, $array2){
    $result = array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
        if(isset($array2[$key])){
            if(is_array($value)){
                $result[$key] = array_concat_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
            }else{
                $result[$key] = $value . ' ' . $array2[$key];
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that:

1. Your first array is assigned to a variable called `$address`
2. Your second array is assigned to a variable called `$city`
3. There are ALWAYS exact matches between the two arrays

**EDIT:**
Great catch by @dev-null-dweller - edited to catch full depth of arrays.

**NOTE**
Example code in question does not have quotes around uploadData key, so that is replicated here:

The following will do what you want:

```
foreach($address as $key=>$value) {
    $newarray = array(
         'uploadData'=>$value['uploadData'] . ' ' . $city[$key]['uploadData'];
    );
}
```

The `$newarray` will contain an array structured per your request.

Comment: Nope, you are missing one level of arrays. As it is now it will trigger warnings and result in array full of entries like `Array Array`

Comment: Thanks cale_b. Your assumptions are correct but dev-null-dweller is right I got a bunch of -     [0] => Array Array
    [1] => Array Array
    [2] => Array Array
    [3] => Array Array

Comment: Huh? You're just re-assigning `$newarray` over and over again... You want to do `$newarray[] = ` and you need to initialize it before the loop.

Comment: Yeah I ended up with an array with just the values from the last row. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

Fetch from both arrays until everything is gone:

```
$final = [];
$key   = 'uploadData';
while ($array1 && $array2)
{
    $final[][$key] = array_shift($array1)[$key] . ' ' . array_shift($array2)[$key];
}
```

See [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) and [*converting to booleans*](http://php.net/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Comment: Nice way to alter `array_merge` with specific items order, but this not answer the questions, there is no concatenations of values here.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: What do you mean? `$final` should be correct.

Comment: no, for sample data posted by OP your final array will have 8 items, when only 4 are desired.

Comment: Ah, now seeing, well then my answer is totally wrong even. However, it can be quickly adopted. *Edit:* Done. *Edit2:* Demo: http://eval.in/5018

Answer (score 0):

Because the two arrays have the same size and there are no associative first level keys to preserve, they can be mapped together with `array_map()` and concatenated.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9f0J2))

```
$streets = [
    ['uploadData' => '1234 Main St'],
    ['uploadData' => '5678 Elm St'],
    ['uploadData' => '9879 New St'],
    ['uploadData' => '9876 Shady Lane'],
];

$cities = [
    ['uploadData' => 'Orlando'],
    ['uploadData' => 'Tampa'],
    ['uploadData' => 'Miami'],
    ['uploadData' => 'West Palm Beach'],
];

var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($s, $c) => ['uploadData' => "{$s['uploadData']} {$c['uploadData']}"],
        $streets,
        $cities
    )
);
```